# Python - Remove HTML-tag with regex

Tags: python, regex

This usually is no hard task, but today I can't seem to remove a simple javascript tag..

The example I'm working with *(formated)*:

```
<section class="realestate oca"></section>
<script type="text/javascript" data-type="ad">
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        window.postscribe && postscribe(document.querySelector(".realestate"),
        '<script src="https://ocacache-front.schibsted.tech/public/dist/oca-loader/js/ocaloader.js?type=re&w=100%&h=300"><\/script>');
    });
</script>
```

The example I'm working with *(raw)*

```
<section class="realestate oca"></section>\n<script type="text/javascript" data-type="ad">\n\twindow.addEventListener(\'DOMContentLoaded\', function(){\n\t\twindow.postscribe && postscribe(document.querySelector(".realestate"),\n\t\t\'<script src="https://ocacache-front.schibsted.tech/public/dist/oca-loader/js/ocaloader.js?type=re&w=100%&h=300"><\\/script>\');\n\t});\n</script>
```

I would like to remove everything from `<script`(beginning of second line) to `</script>`(last line). This will output only the first line, `<section..>`.

Here's my line of code:

```
re.sub(r'<script[^</script>]+</script>', '', text)
#or
re.sub(r'<script.+?</script>', '', text)
```

I'm clearly missing something, but I can't see what.
**Note:** The document I'm working with contains mainly plain text so no parsing with lxml or similar is needed.

Comment: You should know this `[^</script>]` doesn't mean anything except a closing script tag.

Comment: @glibdud I agree, I was only trying to flag it. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343643/1561176

Comment: I think that you should take a look at this answer to using regex to parse "html" http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1561176 . Instead you should be using the correct parser, such as BeautifulSoup. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: @revo Well, if I knew, I wouldn't be asking. Either way, I read somewhere it ment "anything except this" and I'm using it a lot like this ´<[^>]+>´ .

Comment: @InbarRose That made an impression I won't forget. I don't think my document will be able to be parsed, I see it more fit to manually index the tags, group them and then delete everything inbetween.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first regex didn't work because character classes (`[...]`) are a *collection of characters*, not a string. So it will only match if it finds `<script` separated from `</script>` by a string of characters that doesn't include *any* of `<`, `/`, `s`, `c`, etc.

Your second regex is better, and the only reason it's not working is because by default, the `.` wildcard does not match newlines. To tell it you want it to, you'll need to add the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag:

```
re.sub(r'<script.+?</script>', '', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for giving an explanation to why it didn't work!